# Retrofit does not contain a parameter

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit in my Android app for API stuff. Currently I am trying to call a route in my API, but I get this error message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL "online}" does not contain
> "{email}". (parameter #1)

If I call the API via Postman:

```
> myapp.test/api/online
>
> Body:
>
> username: test@test.de
```

It works.

My API service:

```
@POST("online}")
Call<OnlineStatus> online(@Path("email") String email);

@POST("offline}")
Call<OnlineStatus> offline(@Path("email") String email);
```

The API call:

```
Call<OnlineStatus> setStatusOnline;

public void setUserStatusToOnline(String email) {
    setStatusOnline = service.online(email);
    setStatusOnline.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<OnlineStatus>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<OnlineStatus> call, retrofit2.Response<OnlineStatus> response) {
            Log.e("onlineStatusResponse", String.valueOf(response));
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.e("onlineStatus", "Set to online success");
            } else {
                Log.e("onlineStatus", "Set to online error");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<OnlineStatus> call, Throwable t) {
            Toasty.error(LoginActivity.this, "error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Replace your `@Path` with `@Field`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(Your URL like("http://sample/api/online"))
Call<ResponseBody> onLine(@Field("username") String username);
```

This should work...

Comment: @jon not doe xx are u try this one?

Comment: Did this, but it call did not update the database error: `E/onlineStatusResponse: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=Internal Server Error, url=http://myurl.io/api/online}` ` E/onlineStatus: Set to online error`

Answer (score 4):

Your `POST` URL does not contain the parameter that you are trying to set.

```
@POST("offline}")
Call<OnlineStatus> offline(@Path("email") String email);
```

should be `@POST("offline/{email}")`.